# Pandas groupby to create new dataframe with values as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I want to reshape the data by Date in Python as dataframe.

[image]

Required:

[image]

IS there any Pandas function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create additional key by using `cumcount` , then we do `pivot` , Data from jpp

```
df.assign(key=df.groupby('Col1').cumcount()).pivot('key','Col1','Col2')
Out[29]: 
Col1    A    B    C
key                
0     1.0  4.0  6.0
1     2.0  5.0  7.0
2     3.0  NaN  8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `pandas.concat` on series derived from unique values in your key column.

Here is a minimal example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'Col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})

res = pd.concat({k: df.loc[df['Col1']==k, 'Col2'].reset_index(drop=True)
                 for k in df['Col1'].unique()}, axis=1)

print(res)

   A    B  C
0  1  4.0  6
1  2  5.0  7
2  3  NaN  8
```

Comment: Gave you a ++ because I don't believe in dvs with no explanation but you could likely do this easier by iterating over a groupby...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, Thanks - do UV Wen's solution too :).